# Simulate Coded UI Test for Windows Phone application

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, coded-ui-tests

I am going to create an WPF application that simualates the Coded UI Test for Windows Phone 8.1. 
I created a Coded UI Test project for Windows Phone inside Visual Studio 2013 and I understood it code.
So I want to simulate this technology on my WPF application without running VS2013. I could run the Windows Phone emulator without running VS2013 by opening the XDE.exe but know I need to know how to connect to this WP emulator from my WPF application?

So how can I do it, please help me. Thank you so much!.